# Как удалить сразу несколько объектов из DOM?

Tags: jquery

Подскажите, есть ли способ в JQuery удалить через `remove()` сразу несколько объектов с одним идентификаторам?

```
<span id="1"></span>
<span id="1"></span>
<span id="2"></span>
<span id="1"></span>
```

Необходимо удалить все объекты с идентификатором **1**.

Comment: `id` - должен быть уникальным всегда

Comment: Есть ли альтернативные способы для удаления нескольких объектов?

Comment: Смотрите ответ. Пример удаления по классу.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Удаление по классу. Т.к. `id` должен быть уникальным всегда.

```js
$("span.1").each(function() {
  $(this).remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="1">1</span>
<span class="1">1</span>
<span class="1">1</span>
<span class="2">2</span>
```

Comment: ??? - `$("span.1").remove();`

Comment: @Igor, хорошо подметили, можно так.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$("#delete1").click(function(e){
  $("span[id='1']").remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span id="1">One</span>
<span id="1">One</span>
<span id="2">Two</span>
<span id="1">One</span>

<br/>
<button id="delete1">Delete 1</button>
```